# Get only date in format 2018-02-28 in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am using current Date()  function in latest version of angular. I am getting it perfectly correct. But I am getting both Date and Time as shown below:

```
   today = new Date().toISOString();
   console date: 2018-02-08T09:07:15.146
```

I want only 2018-02-08.

Can you guys help me how to get only date in above format, without time.

Thank you.

Comment: Construct it yourself. Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: okay. I will look into the documentation. thank you for sharing this link.

Comment: if it  a matter of rendering .. try do it angular way.

Comment: You can use the Angular DatePipe: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to format the date like **"YYYY-MM-DD"** ionic 3 unless you create your own function. But better if you can use a library like **[moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)**. You can use it very easily to format the date and the time.

Install it using npm /yarn

```
npm install moment --save   # npm
yarn add moment             # Yarn
Install-Package Moment.js   # NuGet
spm install moment --save   # spm
meteor add momentjs:moment  # meteor
bower install moment --save # bower (deprecated)
```

and import like bellow.

```
import * as moment from "moment"; 

const date = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

You can create your own function to return the date like this.

```
const date = new Date();

const formatedDate = date.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

Full Documentation : https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 3):

```
    var d = new Date().toISOString(); // for now
var joinDate = d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + d.getDate();
```

Comment: This should be like follows:  var d = new Date();
var joinDate = d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + d.getDate();

Answer (score 1):

Use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library.

```
var today = new Date();
moment(today).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Answer (score 0):

date Argument is the first value which was returning datetime togetherJust Split the string and get the date Only and Do whatever You Want Then

```
   changeDateFormat2(date){
    const  formated = date.toString().substring(0, 10);
    //let arr = formated.split('-');
    //return `${arr[0]}/${arr[1]}/${arr[2]}`;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
today = new Date().toISOString().split(T)[0];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!