# how to change the time format in ionic 3 typescript

Tags: html, typescript, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a time in 15:12:00 (HH:MM:SS)format. But i need to change this in (3.12 PM) format

```
 <p class="headings" display-format="HH:mm" > <b>Time :</b> {{this.starttime}} </p>
```

In TypeScript

```
 this.starttime = '15:12:00';
```

Comment: I think you should use momentjs. cf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682405/get-only-date-in-format-2018-02-28-in-ionic-3

Comment: can you have the complete date-time object or just time string?

Comment: I Don't need a current time..i already have a time in string @SuperBob

Comment: Just time string  @Naseer

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by prepending '0000-00-00T' with your time string. Then using angular's built in date-pipe with shortTime filter.

```
{{'0000-00-00T15:12:00' | date:'shortTime'}}
```

Angular's official docs for built in [date](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could refer a external library https://momentjs.com/ for advanced datetime formatting techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You can also code it yourself:

```
function formatTime(date:string): string {
  const split = date.split(':');
  const meridiem = +split[0] > 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  let hours = +split[0] % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; 

  return `${hours}.${split[1]}${meridiem}`;
}

this.starttime = formatTime('15:12:00');
```